Adding sqlite file from itunes backup to DB Browser - "Could not open database file"
I am trying to get all messages from my iPhone on my computer. To do so, I have done a full iTunes backup to my windows computer. From some online research I found that the file name "3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28" is a sqlite database with all sent and received messages. I renamed the file to "messages.sqlite" and tried to open it in DB Browser for SQLite, but I get an error "Could not open database file. Reason: file is not a database."

How can I fix this error message and view the messages in the sqlite file? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Did your research include finding the snippet I should probably add that you probably need to make sure that you have the "encrypt backup data" feature turned off before you try this. If the file is encrypted then the header will be encrypted and the result will be that header (first 16 bytes) will not be "SQLite format 3\000" and thus without using the appropriate decryption it will not be an SQLite file by SQlite's handling of the file.

This worked. Thank you!

A common cause of an SQLite database not being an SQLite database when trying to open it is if the database has been encrypted. Which would often (should) be the case when confidential data is stored.
Typically encryption is afforded by encrypting the entire database file. This will encrypt the header (the first 100 bytes of the file) along with the actual data. SQLite checks the header to see if it is a valid SQLite database file, if the first 16 bytes are not exactly SQLite format 3\000 i.e. 53 51 4c 69 74 65 20 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 20 33 00 hex, then SQLite will consider that the file is not an SQLite database.

see https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#magic_header_string

Encryption of the entire file will encrypt the header, thus changing it from it's expected byte stream.
You need to save the file without encryption by disabling the encrypt backup data feature.
